# shortest path through disconnected line segments

Tags: algorithm, geometry, path-finding

I have a seamingly common problem but do not find the name or algorithms to solve it.

Given a set of line segments in euclidean 2d space, I like to find the shortest path through all segments.

This problem for example arises for a plotting machine, that draws on paper using a pen and has to minimize useless traveling times between the things to draw.

What is the name of this problem? Are there simple approximative solutions known?

Answer (score 1):

The problem of minimizing the non-drawing travel distance of the plot pen is very close to a [traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) with the line segment endpoints as vertexes and assigning a cost of 0 between the two ends of a line drawn line segment.

Unlike [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), your problem allows you to start and stop drawing lines in the middle of line segments.  The vertical line on a  [power icon](http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/1432398654659946443.png) is an example of a time you'd want to draw a line in two segments, rather than all at once.  However, I'd guess that this sort of case only comes up when the place you start drawing is different than the place you stop drawing.  If my guess is correct, the solution you'd get by solving the traveling salesmen problem would differ from the optimal solution by only at most the width of the graph.

Comment: Does a solution to the TSP with segments as cost-0 elements are giaranteed to use all segments? I just imagined some verticies could be cheaper to reach via two travel routes touchhing them than the 0-cost route.

Comment: However that could easily be solved by placing another vertex inside the segment.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to adapt a solution for the tsp for this.

You could do this via a genetic algorithm. It won't guarantee that you'll get the best solution, but you can usually get very close in a short time with it.

You basically start with a set of random solutions. You then make slight random changes for each of the solutions, and you measure the travelled distance. You keep the ones with the shortest distances. Just repeat this process until new generations dont provide optimizations or hen you run out of time.